# Weird font rendering in Netbeans on Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans, fonts

I installed NetBeans 6.8 on Linux (Mint, based on Ubuntu 9.10) and I can see that font rendering is very weird. Fonts in NetBeans are just so thin unlike any other program, be it gEdit, Eclipse, Firefox, or whatever.

Does anyone know if it's possible to make fonts in NetBeans look bolder?

Bonus question: AFAIK both Eclipse and NetBeans are written in Java. What gives?

Since a picture's worth a thousand words...
[screenshot](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/3323/screenshotbe.png) (it won't let me post images)

Answer (score 7):

In my case I just had to add `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd` to the `netbeans_default_options` in the configuration file.

You can find the file under `/path/to/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf`.

There's a [wiki article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304063942/http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontRendering) on netbeans.org about this topic:

> if the antialiasing switch *awt.useSystemAAFontSettings* is not set, then Swing text renderer tries to detect the optimum setting for given system and use that. Since 1.6 the renderer implements the following options:
>
> - **off | false | default** - meaning "do not override what has been auto-detected"
> - **on** - use anti-aliasing without sub-pixel rendering
> - **gasp** - use anti-aliasing wit sub-pixel rendering, intended for use both on CRT and LCD
> - **lcd** - use anti-aliasing wit sub-pixel rendering, optimized for LCD
> - **lcd_hbgr** - same as **lcd**, but with different distribution of sub pixels (monitor upside down)
> - **lcd_vrgb** - same as **lcd**, but with different distribution of sub pixels (monitor is vertical)
> - **lcd_vbgr** - same as **lcd**, but with different distribution of sub pixels (vertical again but on other side)

I was using *Apache Netbeans 10.0*.

Comment: To achieve the same avoiding an individual configuration in Linux, it is possible to set this parameter globally in Linux including in your `.bash.profile` the same configuration like this: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'`. Note that the `swing.aatext` parameter acts also over swing applications.

Comment: i should add that i couldn't find the config file on arch linux. i simply added your option to the run command ">netbeans -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd" and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors

You can set font to Bold on the right Font menu.

Check [this post](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/anti_aliasing_font_in_the) on Sun's blog.

I think Eclipse and NetBeans use different libraries to render fonts.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**

- netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh
- netbeans look and feel: Metal
- fedora 27 kde plasma 5
- java-1.8.0-openjdk

If you have plasma 5 desktop you could fix  that with the following steps:

1. System Settings> Fonts> Use anti-aliasing: Enabled
   [image]
2. Next in the Configure option, select like this
   [image]

Now netbeans look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above seemed to work for me. But adding this code snippet globally to my .profile file did resolve the issue for me. credit goes to: gersonZaragocin. I'm using the [Hack font](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/) in this case:

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'`

[image]